# Which C++ cast type is a C cast equivalent to

Tags: c++, c, types, casting

I am guessing that C is just a reinterpret cast and the bit pattern is left as is.

I am trying to understand what would happen when I cast a wider signed value to a narrower signed value.  Is sign preserved, or is it simply the values in the narrower width intepreted as a signed value.

Thanks for any assistance.

edit--this is for C99 compiled c code.  The question isn't what a c++ compiler will do with a sloppy old style cast, but rather if there is anything defined as to what C does.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `static_cast` does. What you describe sounds more like `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: you're right, my bad, I am correcting it.

Comment: I found this in C99

"Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

sounds like I can never know for sure what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need to ask about C++ if you only care about C, but in your example C++ and C still do mostly same thing;

C++ says of these integral conversions:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

C99 says of these integral conversion:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Casting a larger integral value to a smaller, signed integral value will produce the same value if possible and give implementation defined (i.e., non-portable) behavior otherwise.

---

§ 5.4/4 states

> The conversions performed by
>
> - a const_cast (5.2.11),
> - a static_cast (5.2.9),
> - a static_cast followed by a const_cast,
> - a reinterpret_cast (5.2.10), or
> - a reinterpret_cast followed by a const_cast,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.

[...]

> If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one of the ways listed above, the interpretation that
>   appears first in the list is used, even if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed.

C++ is defined such that it is compatible with C; that is, C casts will do the same thing in C++ as they do in C. That means cast notation in C does in fact do different things based on the types being cast between.

Comment: wait I am confused, I am using a C99 compiler. I think what you are answering is what happens with a C++ compiler if I use a c style cast.

Comment: @bames53, can you elaborate, I am not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: @Pablitorun Yes, this answer says what happens in C++ when you use a C style cast, however C++ is designed to have compatible behavior, so if you know what these C++ casts do then you can apply that knowledge to know what C does.

Comment: @Pablitorun Your guess (`C is just a reinterpret cast`) is wrong; C cast is better described by this answer. In your specific case, C cast behaves like a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no equivalent cast.

C cast can behave as all C++ casts (except `dynamic_cast`).

Answer (score 2):

An C cast will eventually result in a C++ cast(except `dynamic_cast`). It is the first cast that succeeds among-st:

- const_cast
- static_cast
- static_cast, then const_cast
- reinterpret_cast
- reinterpret_cast, then const_cast

Comment: wait I am confused, I am using a C99 compiler.  I *think* what you are answering is what happens with a C++ compiler if I use a c style cast.